# Authenticating to SQL Server Reporting Services from MVC

Tags: reporting-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a website (ASP.NET MVC 4) that has  users that need access to SQL Server Reporting Services. In the database for our website we have our user info and the user names are emails (Not sure if emails are allowed as login credentials for SSRS or not?).  What I would like is for a user to be authenticated for the website and SQL Server Reporting services so that we may use the roles, which are also stored in our database, to control which reports users view.

I have read the documentation for implementing a SQL Server Reporting Services Extension but most of the examples implement a logon page for logging onto the SSRS ReportServer site. Whereas I would like my users to be authenticated to view/export reports on my website using a Reporting Services Service. At the very least I would like to authenticate when they log in and be able to redirect them to the Reporting Services Report Manager.

So my question is, is implementing an extension for authentication going to be necessary to view reports on my site?

I'm new to the realm of Reporting Services and am currently educating myself further on the subject, so please feel free to go into unnecessary detail.

Note: The website is being hosted on the same machine as Reporting Services, also SSRS is 2012 edition.

Comment: I think you're asking a (good) question, which is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow. We can't know what's good for your case, only you can. I'd advise you to try an implementation, and get back to SO if you run into specific problems. The more specific a question, the more likely you'll get an answer on SO.

Comment: I did edit a little bit to help clarify, hopefully it helps. I did try implementing my own security extension and I could not get Reporting Services to start once I added it to the Report Server and changed config files as documented by Microsoft.

Comment: You can use emails or any type of data as login credentials for SSRS, if you implement a security extension (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155029.aspx); I have a similar project that has some reports for users in SSRS, but instead of giving permission to users access SSRS, I make my MVC project generate a report in PDF using SSRS and sending to the user. To generate the report in PDF from C#, look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942742/authenticating-against-reportexecution2005-asmx-in-net-core/41943947#41943947